# aplicacion, por defecto en el local host de apache

Tags: apache, xampp, virtualhost

quiero abrir un aplicativo que tengo almacenado en la carpeta htdocs de xampp, el problema es que al iniciar el localhost, no se abre xampp sino un aplicativo Stats pero no es ese el que quiero visualizar, como si estubiera configurado por defecto, entonces al poner el nombre de el que si quiero ver (WFReporting), el me dice que no lo encontró ya que lo esta buscando dentro de la carpeta de Stats.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

como pueden ver la aplicacion Stats se abre solo con digitar localhost, no entiendo por que si esta almacenada en htdocs igual que todas, el aplicativo que quiero abrir se llama WFReporting y al dijitarlo despues de local host, sale este error.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

es decir lo busca en la carpeta de Stats, como puedo hacer para que diferencie las aplicaciones, es decir que solo abra la aplicacion si escribo esto en la url:

para abrir Stats     asi : localhost:8080/Stats

para abrir WFReporting   asi :   localhost:8080/WFReporting

este es el codigo de mi archivo httpd-vhosts de apache

```
ruta : C:\xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts

# Virtual Hosts
#
# Required modules: mod_log_config

# If you want to maintain multiple domains/hostnames on your
# machine you can setup VirtualHost containers for them. Most configurations
# use only name-based virtual hosts so the server doesn't need to worry 
 about
# IP addresses. This is indicated by the asterisks in the directives below.
#
# Please see the documentation at 
# <URL:http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/>
# for further details before you try to setup virtual hosts.
#
# You may use the command line option '-S' to verify your virtual host
# configuration.

#
# Use name-based virtual hosting.
#
##NameVirtualHost *:80
#
# VirtualHost example:
# Almost any Apache directive may go into a VirtualHost container.
# The first VirtualHost section is used for all requests that do not
# match a ##ServerName or ##ServerAlias in any <VirtualHost> block.
#
##<VirtualHost *:80>
##ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host.example.com
##DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/dummy-host.example.com"
##ServerName dummy-host.example.com
##ServerAlias www.dummy-host.example.com
##ErrorLog "logs/dummy-host.example.com-error.log"
##CustomLog "logs/dummy-host.example.com-access.log" common
##</VirtualHost>
```

```
##ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host2.example.com
##DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/dummy-host2.example.com"
##ServerName dummy-host2.example.com
##ErrorLog "logs/dummy-host2.example.com-error.log"
##CustomLog "logs/dummy-host2.example.com-access.log" common
```

Comment: Bienvenido para que entendamos mejor la pregunta pon el código de la llamada de la pagina

Comment: Puedes revisar que no tengas un archivo index en tu directorio raíz ya que si el servidor está configurado para buscar en principio un archivo index y éste existe será lo primero que te muestre al ingresar en tu navegador. Por eso puede que solo veas Stats en vez de WFReporting

Answer (score 0):

Al parecer tu problema está en el fichero de configuración de los vhost de apache:
*`C:\xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf`*

Verifica la configuración que tienes en ese fichero para tus aplicaciones. Seguramente sería bueno pusieras lo que tienes dentro de ese fichero aquí para comprobarlo pero para que te salga como dices, debes poner algo como esto:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/Stats"
    ServerName stats
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/WFReporting"
    ServerName reporting
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: ya edite la pregunta, en que lugar esta configurada la aplicacion Stats por defecto?

Comment: para poner esas lineas que me dices, debo borrar las que ya existen en el archivo al final, ya lo hice y no me funciona sigue saliendo el error

Comment: no me funciono!!